# return data from realtime database and assign to variable not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have the following function

I have an array of two objects each with a nested string array containing uuids.
I am trying to query realtime database and get the users attached to these strings, but I cannot seem to return data and assign it to a variable to use.

TIA

```
const SomeComponent = () => {

    const data = [
      {
       a: 'objectOne',
       userIds: ['3424sfsdf234', '23423dsdf'];
      },
      {
       a: 'objectTwo',
       userIds: ['3424sasdfsdf234', '2334423dsdf'];
      }
    ];

    const getUsers = async (someArray) => {
            const userArr = [];
            someArray?.map(item => {
                item?.userIds?.forEach((username) => {
                    return database()
                        .ref(`users/${username}`)
                        .once('value', snapshot => {
                            return userArr.push(snapshot.val());
                        });
                });
            });
        };

        const x = getUsers(data);

return (
   <>
     {x[0].firstName}
   </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dumb check, but just in case it works, at the end of your getUsers function can you try adding in a `return userArr`?  It's currently not returning the array at the end I think, just pushing it to the end.

Maybe try changing the logic so that inside your forEach, you just push new values onto your userArr and then at the very end of the getUsers function, try doing what I suggested above and returning userArr?